# How to set action listener for JButtons to open respective panels

Tags: java, swing

```
JButton btnB = new JButton("white");
btnB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if (btnB.isSelected()) {
            panel2.setVisible(true);
        }

        if(!btnB.isSelected()) {
```

[When white is clicked, the white panel should appear. When black is clicked, the black panel should appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqsXe.png)

Comment: Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: There is still not enough information on your code, especially regarding the black button, `panel2`, `if (!btnB.isSelected())`, etc

Comment: my code has a mistake. I am a beginner. please try to correct it.

Comment: Yes, in order to know the mistake, we need more information regarding your code. So far, there seems to be no mistake on the part that you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Test extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test frame = new Test();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(buttons, BorderLayout.WEST);
        JButton blackButton = new JButton("Black");
        buttons.add(blackButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JButton whiteButton = new JButton("White");
        buttons.add(whiteButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        content.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 0));
        frame.add(content, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JPanel blackPanel = new JPanel();
        blackPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        JPanel whitePanel = new JPanel();
        whitePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        blackButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                content.removeAll();
                content.add(blackPanel);
                content.revalidate();
                content.repaint();
            }
        });
        whiteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                content.removeAll();
                content.add(whitePanel);
                content.revalidate();
                content.repaint();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much Meini. Its working.

Comment: np bro, but take your time to entirely understand the code, especially what revalidate() is about